# Why lazy loading is resulting in loading the navigation property of the class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

In EF trying to understand lazy loading so marked the enrollments navigation as virtual.

```
class Program {

   static void Main(string[] args) {

      using (var context = new UniContextEntities()) {

         //Loading students only
         IList<Student> students = context.Students.ToList<Student>();

         foreach (var student in students) {

            string name = student.FirstMidName + " " + student.LastName;
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1}", student.ID, name);
    
            foreach (var enrollment in student.Enrollments) {
               Console.WriteLine("Enrollment ID: {0}, Course ID: {1}", 
                  enrollment.EnrollmentID, enrollment.CourseID);
            }
         }

         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
ID: 1, Name: Ali Alexander
       Enrollment ID: 1, Course ID: 1050
       Enrollment ID: 2, Course ID: 4022
       Enrollment ID: 3, Course ID: 4041
ID: 2, Name: Meredith Alonso
       Enrollment ID: 4, Course ID: 1045
       Enrollment ID: 5, Course ID: 3141
       Enrollment ID: 6, Course ID: 2021
ID: 3, Name: Arturo Anand
       Enrollment ID: 7, Course ID: 1050
```

but if the property is marked as non-virtual hence making it a non-lazy or by turning off in configuration then the output is.

```
ID: 1, Name: Ali Alexander
ID: 2, Name: Meredith Alons
ID: 3, Name: Arturo Anand
```

So, what I don't understand is that why turning off lazy loading is resulting in not loading the Enrollments of the students which is still the property of the Students? what's going on?

Comment: Take a look at [the different ways of loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). You need to explicitly load it, if not lazy-loading. Whether it's "Eager loading" or "Explicit loading".

Comment: Because it a reference property, i.e. property representing a relation with another table. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Answer (score 1):

Turning off lazy loading does not mean it will eager-load, it means it simply won't lazy-load, leaving references #null *unless* the DbContext has already loaded them. If you know you want the Enrollments when you load a student then eager load them using `Include` whether lazy loading is enabled or not.

To outline the difference:

With lazy loading:

```
// This line executes SQL like "SELECT * FROM dbo.Students"
IList<Student> students = context.Students.ToList<Student>();

foreach (var student in students) {

    string name = student.FirstMidName + " " + student.LastName;
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1}", student.ID, name);
        
    // This line will execute SQL line "SELECT * FROM dbo.Enrollments WHERE StudentId = {student.StudentId}
    foreach (var enrollment in student.Enrollments) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Vs. Eager loading:

```
// This line executes SQL like "SELECT * FROM dbo.Students s INNER JOIN dbo.Enrollments e ON e.StudentId = s.StudentId"
IList<Student> students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Enrollments).ToList<Student>();

foreach (var student in students) {

    string name = student.FirstMidName + " " + student.LastName;
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1}", student.ID, name);

    // This line no longer triggers any DB call.        
    foreach (var enrollment in student.Enrollments) {
    // ....
    }
}
```

The difference in performance can be quite substantial. If you were to load 100 students and their enrollments, Lazy Loading would result in 101 queries being sent to the Database and waited for. One for the Students, then for each student, another one for the enrollments. If Student had 4 or 5 references that could be 401-501 queries.  With Eager Loading it will always be one query. For large objects with many references or large numbers of records returned this can still easily become a performance bug-bear to be wary of.